# Do queueables have their own governor limits?

Tags: future, queueable-apex, http, timeout

I have a class that makes consecutive API calls. I set the timeout to the **maximum** value allowed by Salesforce (120 seconds) however **sometimes** these are timing out because of the API taking way too long to send a response.

for example:

```
httpPostRequest1(){
 // httpRequest1 takes 65 seconds to receive response
 if (response successful, use data from response to make 2nd api call) {
  httpPostRequest2(); // httpRequest2 takes 60 seconds therefore times out
 }
}
```

So I'm thinking of using Queueables to get around this. For example:

```
httpPostRequest1(){
   // httpRequest1 takes 65 seconds to receive response
   if (response successful, use data from response to make 2nd api call) {
    ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new queueableJob(data from 1st response));
    // does the above job have its timeout limit reset since it is in its own
    // queueable transaction?
   }
}
```

From my testing, the queueable runs in a different transaction as seen in the logs, the first call runs in a **FutureHandler** operation, then a new transaction begins with the **QueueableHandler** operation label.

Theoretically if the api call in the FutureHandlertook 1 minute and 59 seconds, and the response for the QueueableHandler took 10 seconds, would the QueueableHandler fail?

From my understanding it would *not fail* since it is in a different transaction and limits are reset, but please, any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each queueable instance will have its own transaction and governor limits. Therefore, as you suspect, the queueable in your scenario won't fail, as it'll have the entire 120 seconds that all transactions get. In general, just remember that one debug log represents one transaction, and each have their own distinct limits (aside from unit tests, which get two governor limits while running).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for confirming!